# Saving other files in a own data store with fstream

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I am developing at the time a small Filestoresystem, which should store
some files like `.png`´s and so in it.
,
So I read the bytes from the `.png` in a `char` vector successfully, the size of the vector is the same size as the picture (it should be OK).
Then, I wanted to save the bytes in another `.png`.

Actually, I created the File succesfully, but the File is completely empty.

Here is the most important code, I guess:

```
void storedFile::saveData(char Path[]){

std::fstream file;
file.open(Path,std::ios::trunc|std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
if(!file.is_open())
    std::cout << "Couldn´t open saved File (In Func saveData())" << std::endl;
file.write((char*)&Data,sizeof(char) * Data.size());
file.close();}
```

I think that I did it right, but it's not working.

Again, the bytes of the `.png` are stored in `Data`.
I tested after every opening and reading, if it opened and so on, everything worked fine (no error codes appeared).

Comment: We don't know what `Data` is, nor why `std::fstream::write()` would know what to do with it.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong here, maybe you could add the line where you declare Data and also printing the result of file.write and file.close would be interesting.

Comment: How do we know that Data.size() > 0? And what is Data anyways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part looks strange:

```
file.write((char*)&Data,sizeof(char) * Data.size());
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`Data.size()` is a hint that data is a std::vector, so &Data is actually wrong, it should be `(char*)Data.data()`

Comment: Its vector<char>Data; I will try that tomorrow, thanks for the fast reply !

Comment: This works ! My .png file now get saved again correctly, I can even open it in the explorer. Thank you again for your very fast response on my question, excuse me for my bad language skills in english pls :)